# Javascript onSubmit Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, coldfusion

Noob here wants to know how you can validate two fields using a javascript function.
For example the online javascoipt code needs to validate two fields fieldx and fieldy

```
function checkdate(input) {
var validformat = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ //Basic check for format validity
var returnval = false
if (!validformat.test(input.value))
    alert("Invalid Date Format. Please correct and submit again.")
else { //Detailed check for valid date ranges
    var monthfield = input.value.split("/")[0]
    var dayfield = input.value.split("/")[1]
    var yearfield = input.value.split("/")[2]
    var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield - 1, dayfield)
    if ((dayobj.getMonth() + 1 != monthfield) || (dayobj.getDate() != dayfield) || (dayobj.getFullYear() != yearfield))
        alert("Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again.")
    else
        returnval = true
}
if (returnval == false) input.select()
return returnval
}

< /script>
```

Question
How do I use the JavaScript to validated both the fields. I have tried && but didnt work.

```
<cfform action="someactionyoutake.cfm" method ="POST" onSubmit="return 
checkdate(document.formname.fieldx && document.formname.fieldy)">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please use a code beautifier before you paste code...http://jsbeautifier.org/ or a plugin in your Editor.

Comment: You should be consistent : in the JavaScript, you wrote `datecheck()`, and in the HTML, you wrote `checkdate()`.
Also, you should not use on* event in the HTML.
I don't recommend DOM Level 0 access like `document.formname.fieldx` but rather document.getElementById(formOrElementId). `name` attribute is deprecated, BTW.

Comment: *I have tried && but didnt work* You should be using some sort of javascript debugger, like FF's web console, which would you help locate the problem. The [logical `&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FExpressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) is for comparing boolean values, but you are passing in DOM elements instead. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
<cfform action="someactionyoutake.cfm" method ="POST" onSubmit="return datecheck(document.formname.fieldx && document.formname.fieldy)">
```

to

```
<cfform action="someactionyoutake.cfm" method ="POST" onSubmit="return datecheck(document.formname.fieldx) && datecheck(document.formname.fieldy)">
```

Answer (score 1):

just call an intermediate function :

```
<script>
  function checkForm(){
    return datecheck(document.formname.fieldx) && datecheck(document.formname.fieldy)
  }
</script>
<cfform action="someactionyoutake.cfm" method ="POST" onSubmit="return checkForm()">
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged the question with **jquery** try the following snippet

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 var PreFormSubmitValidation = function (event) {
        var isFormValid = true;

        // your validation logic
        if(<Validation Logic Fails>){
             isFormValid = false;
        }

    if(!isFormValid){
                return false; 
                // or can use
                // event.preventDefault(); 
        }
    };

 $("#formId").submit(PreFormSubmitValidation); // calls the method when the form is posted to the server
 });
```

Hope it helps....